# Why the "Uncaught ReferenceError:" when making my HTTP request?

Tags: javascript

```js
"use strict";

(function() {
 var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,England";
 var apiKey = "OMMITTED FOR PRIVACY REASONS"; // Replace "APIKEY" with your own API key; otherwise, your HTTP request will not work
 var httpRequest;
 makeRequest();

 // create and send an XHR request
 function makeRequest() {
  httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = responseMethod;
  httpRequest.open('GET', url + '&appid=' + apiKey);
  httpRequest.send();
 }
 // handle XHR response
 function responseMethod() {
  if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
   console.log(httpRequest.responseText);
  }
 }
})();
```

See link below for a screenshot of the errors, but here's what I'm getting:

1. An Uncaught ReferenceError on line 12 where my onreadystatechange is.
2. I also get an error saying 'responseMethod' isn't defined at
   makeRequest nor when I call it.
3. Also getting an error on the very last line for some reason.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The code looks correct and works with another api, for example:
https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto

Comment: You're not getting three different errors. `Uncaught ReferenceError: responseMethod is not defined` is a single error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good. I just replaced your code with my api key and everything worked (see below).

Can you be more specific about the browser where you get an error?
I tried in the latest chrome and firefox and there is no problem.

```js
"use strict";

(function() {
  var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,England";
  var apiKey = "4ff5002c91520701ec111b6082de9387"; // This key might expire soon.
  var httpRequest;
  makeRequest();

  // create and send an XHR request
  function makeRequest() {
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = responseMethod;
    httpRequest.open('GET', url + '&appid=' + apiKey);
    httpRequest.send();
  }
  // handle XHR response
  function responseMethod() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
      console.log(httpRequest.responseText);
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: I'm using Chrome as well. http://localhost:3000/ 

I'm just as stumped as anyone else here. For what it's worth this is what I'm practicing with: https://www.linkedin.com/learning/building-web-applications-with-ajax/understand-xmlhttprequest?autoplay=true&u=26120114